# angular2-grid - How to wrap content inside ngGridItem?

Tags: angular

I am using below sample. In this I am using code from https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid

When I place html textbox in ngGridItem of sizex: 1, sizey: 1, textbox goes out of grid item. How to wrap content inside grid item or add scroll bar?

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgGrid, NgGridItem} from 'angular2-grid';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h4>My First Angular 2 App</h4>

    <div class="grid" [ngGrid]="{\'max_cols\': 6,\'max_rows\': 4, \'auto_resize\': true}">

        <div class="grid-item" [ngGridItem]="{\'sizex\': 3, \'sizey\': 2}">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = 'pageTitle'/>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item" [ngGridItem]="{\'sizex\': 1, \'sizey\': 1}">

        </div>

        <div class="grid-item" [ngGridItem]="{\'sizex\': 1, \'sizey\': 1}">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = 'pageTitle' />
            <button type="button" (click)="selectGender()">Select Gender</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    `,
    directives: [NgGrid, NgGridItem]
})
```

**NOTE: I can add scrollbar using CSS, but is this the correct way?**

Cheers
Sanket

Answer (score 0):

Sanket, I ran into a similar issue today. Sadly, the angular2-grid is not responsive. It is not bootstrap enabled.

This means that you have to set the size of your textbox based on the size of your device.